# When I Debug my WPF Project Visual Studio runs the wrong Project/Is just blank

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

When i hit F5, for some reason visual studio runs a blank WPF application. And when i hover over the application in the task bar the application name is the name of a different project of mine. Please if you know how to fix this tell me as it is just slowing my everything down for me. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried right clicking on the project you want and selecting it as the startup project?

Comment: yes i've tried that, it doesn't work

Comment: is this a .net core wpf project or a .net framework one?

Comment: it is a net .core one

Comment: Do you have any launchsettings.json files?

Comment: Please, show us your solution structure and `csproj` file

Answer (score 0):

You can try to open the task manager and close all debug programs(Task Manager /Processes/*.vshost.exe *32").

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood, because I think you have a duplicate name problem, or in any case, if the other project is empty, try to delete it, and then try to put the project you want to run as a startup project like this,:
Right click on the project in the solution Explorer --> Set up as a start up project